# Linq to ... and Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have a big question that has been puzzling me for a long time and that I can't seem to get a straight answer for anywhere and I am sure that if someone can answer this with authority and with good examples that it will help not only me but thousands of developers to come.  All I want to know is what are the characteristics of the following concepts and what are the differences between them

**Linq**

**Linq to SQL**

**Linq to Entities**

**Linq to Objects**

**Lambda expressions**

Also, in particular, can someone tell us where constructs such as these fall into the above categories

**Construct 1**

```
var result = from n in nums
             where n < 5
             orderby n
             select n;
```

**Construct 2**

```
Entities.Person.Where(p => p.FirstName == "John").First();
```

Your learned clarifications are eagerly awaited.

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question is general (stack overflow is about specific programing problems) and could be answered just by doing a bit of googling and reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are some over-simplifications here, but for what it's worth:

**Linq** is an API designed for dealing with data sets. `IQueryable`, for instance, comes from the `System.Linq` namespace. **Linq to ...** are different implementations that parse the same  Linq instructions to perform different operations based on how your data is stored. So **Linq to SQL** will parse your `.Where` instruction to produce a sql query with a `WHERE` clause, while **Linq to Objects** would take that same instruction and produce a `foreach`.

A **lambda expression** is pretty much a shorthand for an anonymous delegate. You identify a lambda by the `=>` operator. Your argument list is at the left hand of the `=>` and the expression that can access those arguments and optionally return a result is at the right hand.

Your two code examples are different syntaxes in which Linq queries can be written. They are called Query syntax and Method syntax, respectively.